# Binomcdf, can't understand something about an answer

Tags: probability

```
It is known that disks produced by a produced by some company will be 
defective with probability .01 independently of each other.  The 
company sells the disks in packages of 10 and offers a money-back 
guarantee if more than one of the 10 disks is defective.  What's the 
probability that a package will be returned?
```

The solution is `1 - binomcdf(10,.01,1)`.  I get the `binomcdf(10,.01,1)` part but I don't get the `1 -` part.

Why are we subtracting 1?

Answer (score 2):

The CDF represents the probability that $1$ or fewer disks are defective.

The problem asked for the probability that **more than** $1$ disk is defective.

That is the one minus the CDF.